# Wie benutzt man „nach dem Motto“?

Tags: single-word-request, colloquial

Ich habe mal jemandem zugehört, der so oft wie möglich *nach dem Motto* in seiner Erzählung einsetzte. Daher denke ich, dass *nach dem Motto* was anderes als "according to the motto" or "along the lines of" bedeuten könnte. Aber was?

<sup>Aus dem Kontext konnte man es manchmal als *als ob* interpretieren, die Bedeutung finde ich aber nicht.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Die Wendung kann je nach Kontext mehrere Anwendungen haben.

Allgemeine Richtlinie:

> Die Gruppe handelte nach dem Motto: Was du nicht willst, dass man dir
>   tu...

Eigene Richtlinie, Wahlspruch, Leitgedanke (der auch ironisch formuliert und gemeint sein kann):

> Er argumentierte stets nach seinem Motto: Trau keiner Statistik, die du nicht selbst gefälscht hast.

(Subjektive, relativierende) Klassifizierung des Verhaltensmusters eines anderen:

> Und dann verlässt er den Arbeitsplatz immer eine halbe Stunde zu früh,
>   nach dem Motto, es wird ohnehin keiner merken.

Comment: Ja, eben die letzte Anwendung ist die, für die ich mich interessiere.

Comment: @c.p. Eine passende englische Entsprechung zu dieser Variante kann ich leider nicht liefern.

Answer (score 5):

Es kann auch als eine relativ hohle Phrase (wie z. B. "like" oder auch "as it were") verwendet werden.

Comment: Besonders ein Gebrauch "so oft wie möglich" legt die hohle Phrase nahe...

Comment: Ich sag mal, das hört sich, ich sag mal, sehr wahrscheinlich an.